# Selecting data from SQL Server with Accent Marks not working on PHP

Tags: php, sql

For some reason I cant retrieve data from a query to a username with accent marks, but the same data retrieving works perfectly if the user has no accent marks.

This is the PHP query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE User= 'Róger'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
$UserID = $row['ID'];
echo "ID is: " . $UserID;
```

This is my result on website:

```
ID is:
```

This is what i get from var_dump($query);

```
"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE User= 'Róger'"
```

Now, if we change $query from

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE User= 'Róger'";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE User= 'Robert'";
```

Then it properly shows up the UserID.

Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: This sounds like an encoding problem in your PHP script (assuming the same queries would work executed directly on MySQL).

Comment: Its SQL Server, sorry for the wrong tag. In fact querys are directly working on MySQL. All I have related on my enconding PHP script is: ini_set('mssql.charset', 'utf-8'); and the DB connection. The rest of the file is just this query and this echo, since i'm trying to solve it from a different file.

Answer (score 1):

It got fixed by adding `'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8'` to the DB connection file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use * for this call.
If necessary, list all required columns instead of *.

I guess, It seems that this is enough to put the userid in here.

```
SELECT UserID FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE User= N'Robert'
```

you need use N
or use UTF-8